# Win batch scripting: extract substring from string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to extract a substring from a string based on the delimiter `/`. The substring extraction has to be hungry so the I want to get all characters from the string up to the last `/`. Example:

String: `/ab/bcd/casd/adsd/se/23`

Substring: `/ab/bcd/casd/adsd/se/`

P.S.: I have seen other QnAs and they don't answer the specific part where the last delimiter occurrence should be used to extract the substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "String=/ab/bcd/casd/adsd/se/23"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%string%") DO SET substring=%%~pa
SET "substring=%substring:\=/%"
echo %substring%

GOTO :EOF
```

You're a little short on specifics. This may work for you assuming the string involved doesn't contain `\`. Treat the string as a filename, remove the "name+extension" then reverse the `/` to `\` conversion.

Comment: Not an issue with the example given, but this will fail if the string begins with a drive letter. Easily solved by using `in ("a:\a%string%")` and then after assigning `"substring=%%~pa"`, remove the `\a` with `%substring:~2%`, and then convert \ back into /.